When I turn my laptop it shows the windows xp loading screen as normal but suddenly a blue screen pops up and quickly disappears
When I turn my laptop it shows the Windows XP loading screen as normal, then a blue screen pops up and quickly disappears and it immediately reboots saying windows did not turn on properly - pick the following options:

Safe mode (three options)

Last know configuration

Start windows normally


What do I do? I have 4gb of RAM an i3-3120M 160gb HDD. I recently found my dads old hdd which gives me the error

No, you don't. Windows XP is out of support for a decade now and shouldn't be used. Your hardware specs are enough for the currently supported Windows 10 (until October 2025) or ANY Linux (preferable). There's absolutely No reason whatsoever to insist on using Windows XP. If used online it's dangerous, for you, your home network and everybody else, just don't.

"I recently found my dads old hdd which gives me the error" What does that mean? You swapped your dads HDD with the one in the machine?

If they were flagged as rude or abusive an admin may have removed your other comments. The other commentors are correct: it is unreasonable to expect an old drive plugged into a new computer to boot, and if you just want to get the files from the old drive, that does not require you to boot from that drive. There are many questions already on this site about connecting hard drives and recovering data.

music2myear I'm trying to boot into windows because I'm trying the operating system for a retro perspective. I've done this with windows 7 and it works perfectly. I even tried cloning the hard drive but nothing worked

Your laptop with an Intel® Core™ i3-3120M, a CPU that was released Q3'12 (3rd quarter 2012), was sold, at the earliest, late 2012 and more likely throughout 2013 or later. This places it as contemporary with Windows 8. It may have had a Windows 7 downgrade option but that's all.
Your computer is NOT even compatible with Windows XP.

I searched up is my CPU compatible with windows xp and it says yes. also windows xp end of support was 2014 so they kept supporting chips until that time

Computers with Windows 8 preinstalled never had drivers for XP.

i found drivers for windows xp tho
